# batch file : checking calendar

Tags: batch-file

How I can check the date using a calender , what I want to do is that a user insert a date in this way 2012/07/15 , and i want to check if this date exist in the calender .
for example if he insert 2012/14/13 or even 2012/02/31 , i tried to do that manually but its really hard , so my qustions are :

1. is there a native function(or even 3d party tools) to check date in calender ?
2. if the user insert date and hour , I want to give same result with different time zone places ?

Comment: You say you want to check a date in a calendar using batch to see if it exists, what calendar are you checking against? We can't give you code to do this unless we know what your doing.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear, I want the user to input a date , but i dont want to accept any thing he wright , I want to accept answer of a date that really exit the a normal calender of a normal year

Comment: Ah right, thanks for clarifying. I may have slightly misunderstood but that makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subroutine below is comprised of two parts. First it check the date given in 1st parameter and return ERRORLEVEL=1 if the date is bad. You may insert a year valid range if you wish (otherwise, remove the yyOK parts).

Then it takes a base hour and time-zone adjust in 2nd and 3rd parameters and show the adjusted date.

```
:validateDate result= YYYY/MM/DD [HH HHAdjust]
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set daysPerMonth[!i!]=%%a
)
set result=Invalid date
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%2") do set yy=%%a& set mm=%%b& set dd=%%c
set /A yy=%yy%, mm=10%mm% %% 100, dd=10%dd% %% 100, yyMOD4=yy%%4 >NUL 2>&1 || goto exit
if %yyMOD4% equ 0 set daysPerMonth[2]=29
set /A yyOK=0, mmOK=0, ddOK=0
rem Modify year limits as you wish (or remove they):
if %yy% geq 1900 if %yy% leq 2015 set yyOK=1
if %mm% geq 1 if %mm% leq 12 set mmOK=1
id %dd% geq 1 if %dd% leq !daysPerMonth[%mm%]! set ddOK=1
set /A dateOK=yyOK*mmOK*ddOK
if %dateOK% neq 1 goto exit
rem Date is correct
set result=%yy%/%mm%/%dd%

rem Adjust the hour to different time zone, if given
rem %3=base hour, %4=adjust with sign (+ or -)
if "%4" equ "" goto exit
set /A newHH=10%3 %% 100 %4
if %newHH% gtr 23 (
   rem Pass to next day
   set /A newHH-=24, dd+=1
   if !dd! gtr !daysPerMonth[%mm%]! (
      set /A dd=1, mm+=1
      if !mm! gtr 12 (
         set /A mm=1, yy+=1
      )
   )
)
if %newHH% lss 1 (
   rem Pass to previous day
   set /A newHH+=24, dd-=1
   if !dd! lss 1 (
      set /A mm-=1
      if !mm! lss 1 (
         set /A mm=12, yy-=1
      )
      for %%m in (!mm!) do (
         set /A dd=daysPerMonth[%%m]
      )
   )
)
set result=%yy%/%mm%/%dd% %newHH%

:exit
endlocal & set %1=%result%
exit /B
```

Test this program and report any problem.

**EDIT**: I have modified previous program to fit new OP's requirements.

The subroutine no longer returns an ERRORLEVEL value with the result. It must be called now with a new first parameter that indicate the variable that will receive the result, that will be "Invalid date" if original date is bad. If a base and adjustment hours are given, returned value include the adjusted date and hour. For example:

```
call validate.bat adjusted= 2012/3/5 3 -2
if "%adjusted%" neq "Invalid date" (
   echo Adjusted date and hour are: %adjusted%
)
```

Antonio

Comment: excuse me i am still new to scripting , but how i can use this script ,what i did  call:validateDate YYYY/MM/DD HH HHAdjust 2012/05/04 but it didnt work

Comment: The first line: `:validateDate YYYY/MM/DD [HH HHAdjust]` show the _format_ of the call; for example: `call :validateDate 2012/05/04`. To adjust for a time zone, also include a base hour and an adjustment: `call :validateDate 2012/05/04 %hour% +6`. I suppose you will get the hour from current time: `set hour=%time:~0,2%` **EDIT**: I just fixed a problem when the base-hour have a left zero; please, copy the program again!

Comment: Excuse me? The _date_ is adjusted based on a given base time and adjustment hours, as you requested. Want you also the Batch file show the adjusted _time_? Why you didn't requested that, in first place? You wrote this: "hour=13 i must subtract -2 hours , so I should write hour=11 not 13 , now this isn't a big thing". So? If you change the specifications after each result, when your specifications will be fulfilled?

Comment: ok sorry my mistake I will try to modify code by myself , thank you

Comment: just a question , from a file bat i want to call your scirpts---- call validate.bat 2012/3/5 3 -2 , is there a way to return values from your script to my bat file ? becuase i want to put them in variable

Comment: I have modified the program above, check it

Comment: thank you very much, even if I did modify it but your solution is more clever

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple native batch command that will validate your string.

Here is a batch subroutine that can be used to validate the date string.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "dt="
set /p "dt=Enter a date in yyyy/mm/dd format: "
if not defined dt exit /b
call :validateDate dt && (echo date is valid) || (echo ERROR: date is invalid)
exit /b

:validateDate
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !%~1!|findstr /rx "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]" >nul || exit /b 1
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%A in ("!%~1!") do (
  set /a "yyyy=10000%%A%%10000, mm=100%%B%%100, dd=100%%C%%100" || exit /b 1
)
if %mm% lss 1 exit /b 1
if %mm% gtr 12 exit /b 1
if %dd% lss 1 exit /b 1
set "months=;1-31;2-28;3-31;4-30;5-31;6-30;7-31;8-31;9-30;10-31;11-30;12-31;"
for /f "delims=;" %%A in ("!months:*;%mm%-=!") do set maxDays=%%A
set /a "divBy4=yyyy%%4, divBy100=yyyy%%100, divBy400=yyyy%%400"
if %mm% equ 2 if %divBy4% equ 0 (
  if %divBy100% neq 0 set /a maxDays+=1
  if %divBy400% equ 0 set /a maxDays+=1
)
if %dd% gtr %maxDays% exit /b 1
exit /b 0
```

It will only accept 4 digit years, 2 digit months, and 2 digit days as you have posted in your question. If you want to support 1 digit months or days, then change the FINDSTR to the following:

```
echo !%~1!|findstr /rx /c:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]" ^
                       /c:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]" ^
                       /c:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]" ^
                       /c:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]">nul || exit /b 1
```

I don't understand what you want to do with the date and time zones.

Comment: ok there is the thing , there is sever that have files on it , if you insert date and time it will give you the wanted file , the problem is the different of time zone , for example if i want to download the file 2012/05/14 , hour=13 i must subtract -2 hours , so I should write hour=11 not 13 ,   now this isn't a big thing. the thign is if i subtract -2 from hour=01 then i should go back a day and if the day was 1 then i must go back a month and here it depend on the month it maybe have 31,30,29 days . by the way I dont want a native thing , any tool would be ok

Comment: @dbenham: Your adjustment for centurial years is wrong. A centurial year is leap if it can not be divided by 400, so 1700, 1800 and 1900 _are_ leap years, but your method omit they...

Comment: @Aacini - You stated that wrong, but you are correct that my code was wrong. 2000 is leap year because it is divisible by 400. 1700,1800,1900 are not leap years. Thanks. The code has been fixed.

Comment: @dbenham: Yes, you are right and I was wrong, but I was also right so you was wrong! :) (I wrote the opposite case in my comment). Whatever, 2000 _is_ leap year and your original code omitted it...